# Drawing Effect Sketches - any tools support it?

Tags: legacy-code

Could anybody tell me if there are any tools could help to draw Effect Sketches described in Michael Feathers' book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code"??

The purpose of Effect Sketches is to show the interactions between the fields and methods in a group of coupling classes while browsing through the code.

For more information about Effect Sketches, please refer to the following blogs:
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/11/04/reading-code-unity/
http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/02/23/coding-effect-sketches-and-the-mikado-method/

Thanks!

Ben Wu

Answer (score 1):

The second article actually demonstrates such a tool: [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). Just look at the example given and write up a dot file. Then run it through the `dot` command line program form graphviz and you'll end up with the graph that looks like the one in the article.

A dot file is simply a description of relationships. For more on dot file syntax read up the documentation from the graphviz site or this wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)

Comment: Thanks, slebetman. What I meant was a tool which could read the methods and fields in my classes and draw the Effect Sketches automatically. Although graphviz is half-automatic, I'd rather draw it by hand.